# Check if cell contains Non-Alpha characters SAS

Tags: sas

I am looking for function if variable contains Non-Alpha characters

I found the function

notalpha

```
data test;
set final_step1;
f_test = notalpha(first_name);
l_test = notalpha(last_name);
keep emplid first_name last_name f_test l_test;
run;
```

but it showing like this

```
Last_name Abate  f_test
John             4
```

it supposed to show 0

notalpha("%%%%%"); is supposed to show 1 from

https://books.google.com/books?id=d58uBZPO0IwC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=notalpha+sas&source=bl&ots=XKM3DlDol-&sig=ACfU3U1SReZzc5zjsXcCdls3twlUReOxBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV_Pmb_vXiAhXkna0KHWrmBYgQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=notalpha%20sas&f=false

Is any function it finds non alphabetic value on SAS or I made mistakes on the code?

Comment: That doesn't look right.  The fourth character in `John` is an alpha character.  But the space that follows it is not an alpha.  So the result should be 5 and not 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TRIMN` function to remove trailing spaces and return a 0-length string (if necessary) when name is blank.

```
pos_notalpha = notalpha ( TRIMN ( name )) ;
```

If you have leading spaces as well, use `STRIP`

```
leftedpos_notalpha = notalpha ( STRIP ( name )) ;
```

From helps

> **NOTALPHA Function**
>
> Searches a character string for a nonalphabeticcharacter, and returns
>   the first position at which the character isfound.

and

> **TRIMN Function**
>
> Removes trailing blanks from character expressions,and returns a
>   string with a length of zero if the expression is missing.

and

> **STRIP Function**
>
> Returns a character string with all leading and trailing blanks removed.
>   …
>   The STRIP function returns the argument with all leading and trailing
>   blanks removed. If the argument is blank, STRIP returns a string with a
>   length of zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to anyalpha function for this purpose, see code below:

```
data have;
input name $10.;
anyalp=anyalpha(name);
if anyalp=0 then notalpha=1;
else if anyalp>0 then notalpha=0;
drop anyalp;
datalines;
%%%%%
01233
abcdef
@bc
abc123
;
run;

proc print data=have; run;
```

Documentation: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002194060.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
lengthn(compress(first_name,".",'a'))
```

compress removes all alphabetic chars. If the length of the resulting string is greater than zero, then it contains non alphabetic chars.

Comment: The *NotAlpha-ness* is not readily apparent but it works.  Cycle wise `compress` would have to always scan all characters, and `notalpha` can stop at the first failing character, but the function nesting probably eliminates that ridiculously small differential.  The `,".",` can be replaced with no-arg double comma, `,,`